# Permit member-only pricing

Tags: civievent, civimember, webform-civicrm

**Goal: Provide member discount pricing for some events and member exclusivity for other events.**

I realize **cividiscount can provide membership discounts** - is it required or can it be achieved via price-sets too?

Can **event registration be restricted by membership status** (free or for fee)  Can't see how to do that with cividiscount.

**I can do it with a specific civicrm-webform** but wanted to see if I'm missing something in native civicrm.

I would guess that member-only events would be a common use case.

Answer (score 1):

The [Group Price](https://github.com/tadpolecc/civicrm_groupprice) Extension states that it

> allows you to limit the display of individual prices in price sets to specific groups. This can be used to implement members-only pricing for events, as well as other use cases.