# CiviEvent - Members Only Pricing

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, civimember

I was curious to know whether or not it was possible to add members-only pricing to an event. I have a few default prices for an event but I wanted to be sure if it was possible or not to be able to add specific prices for members-only.

I realize there is a question similar here: [Permit member-only pricing](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3450/permit-member-only-pricing) but that was 2 years ago and I was wondering if anything ever changed, I can't seem to find anything else on the subject and I figure there has to be a way otherwise I feel more people would ask about this...

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use CiviDiscount.

1. Create a random code.
2. Place the discount amount - either as a monetary amount or percentage.
3. Add other settings to your desire.
4. Use drop down - discount for events - Select the event.
5. Use drop down Automatic discounts - use Automatic discount for existing members of type - chose the types.
6. Then under Automatic discount for Membership Statuses - choose the status - I would choose current and new - depending on your settings.
7. Choose price field options (under additional options) to choose the exact items you want discounted. Ignore this if all items are treated the same, such as 10% discount across the board. (thanks for reminder KilakwaBT)
8. Add any other settings to your desire.

If the member is logged in, all the discounts will be applied automatically if all of the conditions are met (no code needed).  As members tend to forget to login, you may want to write a note on the event page saying Members - Login for a special discount - or something to that extent.

Comment: The drop down "Price Field Options" comes in handy if you wish to only discount certain items. Such as, discounting the registration but not add-on items such as meals

Answer (score 2):

There is also the [Group Price](https://github.com/tadpolecc/civicrm_groupprice) extension which states that it

> allows you to implement things like members-only pricing for events

Comment: Thats a nice extension you got there. :) So nice its should be added to the "add new" section of CiviCRM. (never know how to differentiate the extensions directory on civicrm.org vs the one on your own Civi install.)

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Acknowledgement to Wayne Eaker of Tadpole Collective. Not one of Fuzion's extensions.